# Modifying one array modifies another one I made from it

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var allCoords = [{ x: 2, y: 3 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }];
var emptySpaces = allCoords;

emptySpaces.splice(0, 1);
console.log(allCoords.length);
console.log(emptySpaces.length);
```

I do not understand why both of these output "1".  Why is the original array, `allCoords` being modified, when I only want the second one, `emptySpaces` to be edited?

Comment: the simple answer is they are the same array. `emptySpaces = allCoords` creates a reference , not a copy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modify your code like this:

```
(function testing() {
    var allCoords = [];
    var emptySpaces = allCoords.slice();

    emptySpaces.push({
        x: 1,
        y: 2
    });
    console.log(allCoords.length);
    console.log(emptySpaces.length);
}());
```

Comment: In this example anyway, `allCoords.slice()` should just be `[]`. No reason to clone an empty array.